# Google Compute Engine (GCE) grant access via sftp to other users

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a VM in CGE with CentOS 7.

I can connect to the VM using `sftp` and `gcloud` command, but now I need grant access to others users to some directories..

The issue that I have is that I cant grant or create sftp accounts for others users... it's possible set the accounts for access to the server using sftp only to the directories that I need? it's posible in GCE?

Best,

Comment: You can follow the instructions described in answer of the case below (Chroot access): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110593/how-can-i-create-an-sftp-user-in-centos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup a proper SFTP user in linux?](http://serverfault.com/questions/61706/how-to-setup-a-proper-sftp-user-in-linux)