# How can I set a global sftp chroot for a group (or all) users on a server

Tags: security, linux, sftp, chroot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set up a chrooted SFTP login with OpenSSH](https://serverfault.com/questions/4492/set-up-a-chrooted-sftp-login-with-openssh)

I am not familiar with chroot jails so please forgive my ignorance.

From my understanding you would normally chroot a user to their home directory - ex: /home/username.

I would like to chroot all (or ideally a specific group of users) to a certain directory.

For example a user should be able to get to /web/TheirUserDir and /web/GroupDirThatAreIn - basically I would like to make it so the group "webusers" can not go about /web.

Thanks in advance for ideas, thoughts and answers.

Comment: What software are you using to server out SFTP?

Comment: I am using OpenSSH SFTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible using (only) chroot, as /web/userDir and /web/groupDir  share /web as their lowest common root.

Forcing them to use sftp and limiting them to /web is as close as you can get:

> Match group webusers
>       ForceCommand internal-sftp
>       X11Forwarding no
>       AllowTcpForwarding no
>       ChrootDirectory /web

The rest can (and should) be handled by ACLs.